# Where can I get the AS/400 Client Access Express for Windows software?

Tags: windows, ibm-midrange

Where can I get "AS/400 Client Access Express for Windows"?

Is this free (in terms of money) software and where can I download it? I couldn't find any workable download link.

Thank you very much for your help.

EDIT

---

I need this SW, because client wants to replace their old workstations with new one and they need this to run their bussines (to connect to some other company's mainframe).
Problem is that they lost their install CD and that the other company won't get them another or so they say.

So there is no chance to download this from the internet ?

Comment: Not sure why the down vote. Definitely relevant.

Comment: I completely disagree with the closing of this question. Please reopen.

Comment: have you tried contacting IBM customer support ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An installable image of Client Access (now called [IBM i Access for Windows](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/access/index.html)) can usually be found on the system in the IFS path "/QIBM/ProdData/Access/Windows/Install/Image" or "/QIBM/ProdData/CA400/Express/Install/Image".

---

**You can install directly from the system or download the installation image using FTP**.

Try to access the network share at `\\<ip address>\QIBM\ProdData\Access\Windows\Install\Image`.

If that doesn't work try to download the image using FTP:

```
ftp <ip address>
cd /QIBM/ProdData/Access/Windows/Install/Image
bin
prompt
mget *
quit
```

For more information see [Installing iSeries Access for Windows on the PC](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/rzaij/rzaijinstallxe1.htm).

---

There are also free and commercial alternatives available depending on the functionality that is required.

- [Mochasoft TN5250](http://www.mochasoft.dk/) - Commercial, Windows and Mac
- [IBM Personal Communications](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/network/pcomm/) - Commercial
- [TN5250J](http://tn5250j.sourceforge.net/) - Free, Java based
- [tn5250 for Linux](http://tn5250.sourceforge.net/) - Free, Linux

And finally the AS/400 telnet server supports [VT emulation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/rzaiw/rzaiwmodevtxxx.htm) so that you can connect using any telnet client including those built into Windows, Mac, Linux, etc.  The keymap is a little unusual but it's perfectly usable.

Comment: Completely forgot about that.

Answer (score 4):

1. If your system is on maintenance, you can easily** call up your business partner (or IBM) to get the software.
2. If you don't have maintenance. It gets more difficult and highly depends on what you are looking for. If your just looking for 5250 (green screen) access. Do search for 5250 and your platform (Windows/Linux/OS X) for many free and low-cost options. If you are looking for the i Navigator package, I am not sure what you can do.

** Easy being a relative term much like getting a root canal is easy or getting a tour of Fort Knox is easy.

Another source for information may be asking the same question on [MIDRANGE-L](http://murl.me/midrangel).