# Connecting to AS/400 hardware

Tags: hardware, connection, ibm-midrange

In about 2-3 weeks I'm getting an old AS/400 server (something 9406, probably 6xx or 8xx) to learn OS/400 from administrators point of view.

Will I need some special hardware to connect and do IPL (and probably install OS/400)?

UPDATE:
I dont have access to any twinaxial console or a way to obtain it.

Comment: I don't believe you need anything *really* special. Ours has a dumb terminal connected to the back with twinax, but I am under the impression you can IPL it with just the operator panel on the front. The hardware is not really my thing, so don't take this as golden - just things I've gleaned over the years talking about it with the guy that has IPL'ed it a few times for updates and such. I'm positive there is more to it than pressing a few buttons (start QINTER and other subsystems etc.), but it is in my server room, and I'm almost certain we have nothing special required to IPL the thing.

Answer (score 2):

There are primarily 3 types of console connections on the AS/400:

- Twinax console - Legacy connection requiring a 5250 compatible terminal or hardware emulator using [twinaxial cabling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twinaxial_cabling)
- LAN console - Common [IBM Access](https://serverfault.com/questions/278936) operations console software over ethernet
- HMC console - High-end hardware console for managing partitions (virtualization)

Which one(s) you have will depend on the hardware configuration.

See [System i Information](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/powersys/v3r1m5/topic/ipha8/hwparent_systemi.htm) (hardware) and [IBM i Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp) (software) for more information.

Comment: Console connections via modem are also possible for those times when one must connect remotely.